# Dynamic loading of vue components with vite working on dev but not server

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vite

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<component :is="componentVaiable"></component>
```

Where `componentVaiable` is one of two components. I've tried importing these components the following ways:

1:

```
const x = defineAsyncComponent(() =>  import("./Fields/X.vue"))
const y = defineAsyncComponent(() =>  import("./Fields/Y.vue"))
```

2:

```
const { x } = await import("./Fields/X.vue");
const { y } = await import("./Fields/Y.vue");
```

3:

```
import x from "./Fields/X.vue";
import y from "./Fields/Y.vue";
```

Now all of these examples work fine when I run `npm run dev` but when I build my project and run with SSR or `vite preview` it won't load the components. So basically, this won't run on production or staging servers.

I've tried having a look around but couldn't find anything that worked.

Using Vue composition API and Vite.

UPDATES:

Starting my server with `node bootstrap/ssr/ssr.mjs`

Error I was getting was "Component 'x' is not found".

Thank you for the comments that are trying to help but I think it's time for me to move on. I'll post the workaround I did as an answer.

Comment: are you using inertia for `SSR`?

Comment: Your first approach should work. I'm using it in my project. So you need to clarify what is not working. Is there any console error logs? Does your variable `componentVaiable` get the right value? How do you set up your SSR server?
Btw, `vite preview` is not the proper way to serve SSR.

Comment: Yes I'm using SSR, the componentVaribale is getting the correct value, it works in dev mode (with hot reloads). I'm not on my computer at the moment but the error I get is  something like "cannot find component X".

Comment: Also I do run the server correctly too as I need it for other parts of the project that work. I can add more details on Monday as I'm not on my computer for the weekend. I will also post the workaround I did to help others

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on stackblitz.com? You can clone [this template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-l1ehlx?file=README.md), it already runs on SSR. Keep it as minimal as possible. Btw, please tag the ones you want to talk with in the comment because I completely missed your comment :)

Comment: @Duannx Hey there, in "app.js" you'll see a comment saying to update the variable ref from 'a' to 'b'. It works in this example so there must be something wrong with my setup. Here is the is the updated link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-o9w6cu?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2Fa.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2Fb.vue

Comment: As I am on the clock for this and I've already found a solution, I might be less engaged now. I will still keep an eye on this thread in case someone else needs help or finds something (now that I have a working solution in the stackblitz link and a weird workaround to help people with)

Answer (score 0):

for a work around I thought "If only I could just load everything in and forget about all this" and that's what we did.

I made a new components, lets call if 'fields'. That component simply loads in everything that might be a variable like so

```
<template>

    <x v-if="field === 'x'" @change="saveAttributes" :attributes="attributes" ></x>
    <y v-if="field === 'y'"  @change="saveAttributes" :attributes="attributes" ></y>

</template>
```

But from comments and other similar questions on the web it looks like the original way I attempted should work, I must just have something weird going on.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that is less of a workaround. @duannx asked me to put the example up on stackblitz and I actually got it working. So this might be a good reference for anyone struggling.

You can change 'a' to 'b' where I have commented so on app.js to test what wasn't working on my local machine but is working on stackblitz. Hopefully this can help someone but I think I'm moving on

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-o9w6cu?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2Fa.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2Fb.vue